# How does the MEAN or MERN stack work in this hypothetical scenario?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, twitter, bots

I've taken some backend courses, but they all have one thing in common. They only teach you the basics and then show you how they come together through a simple application.

What I want to know is how does a MERN or MEAN stack work in an Twitter bot.

The Twitter bot does the following:

- Follow and unfollows users
- Looks up hashtags
- Displays information about accounts onto charts in the dashboard
- Retweeting other accounts' tweets

If someone can also explain the account connection process that would be awesome. Some account linking processes I've seen were fetching users' data with API. If there are other account linking methods please let me know.

This is just the basic information. I just want to know how these features fit into the MERN or the MEAN stack. I want to find out how REACT or ANGULAR is used in these situations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection process to Twitter's API uses their authentication, which I believe is an initial POST to a oauth route and then getting a bearer token. You pass this token with each auth-required API call in order to use it.

Backend examples like that don't use React or Angular. This are simple about MongoDB, Express, and NodeJS. If you want, you can create a simple frontend to display nicer-looking information about the bot using Angular or React.

Comment: So are you saying that the API is where I get all of the data for the users? Likes, retweets, followers, etc? And with this data from the API, I implement it into the backend using NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB? And React or Angular is used to take the data and present it to the front end? Did I get it correct?

Comment: Yes. The frontend will get the data from your server through an API and display it. The backend will have routes through Express to return JSON data about tweets.